# How to get the current color of SwiftUI View?

Tags: swiftui

I have a controller `NSHostingController`. And, I would like to know the current background color of the `rootView`.

However, it seems that the `View` does not have any property that allows the get the background color for that view.

```
@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public protocol View {

    /// The type of view representing the body of this view.
    ///
    /// When you create a custom view, Swift infers this type from your
    /// implementation of the required `body` property.
    associatedtype Body : View

    /// Declares the content and behavior of this view.
    var body: Self.Body { get }
}
```

Comment: In short, you can't. Also, colors in SwiftUI are _views_, not colors, so the value won't be much use to you if your intention was to use it as a `UIColor` from a UIKit view.

Comment: I managed to sort of work around the problem by passing a closure to the SwiftUI `View`. So, it can update the Color of my NSHostingController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SwiftUI you manipulate with models not with views. So if you need to know current color, then put it in some model and pass it around, like

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var backgroundColor: Color
}

struct SomeView: View {
   @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel

   var body: some View {
      Text("Some view")
        .background(vm.backgroundColor)
   }
}
```

so if you need to know somewhere current background color you ask it not in view but in view model where it is known and managed by you explicitly.